# Is it safe to use factory class outside the DLL?

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, factory, abi

I would like to use something like this in my application (which is going to be the exe):

```
auto obj = factory.create("obj");
```

In the DLL, the factory looks like:

```
class APIMACRO factory {
    public:
        static abstractType* create(const char* type);
}
```

Is there any safe way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be not safe here? Looks OK, it's a common pattern to provide a factory in the library. Unless you will do sth wrong outside the code that you presented, of course.

Comment: Because I allocate memory with the dll, and I will free it in the exe. Is it completely safe assuming the worst case (different compilers)?

Comment: No, both allocation and deallocation will take place in the memory space assigned to your executable by the system. Shared library linked to your executable does not behave as a separate process on it's own. It is loaded on your executable startup and its symbols are exposed for you to use them. So, it is completely safe. This is how shared libraries are supposed to be used.

Comment: Thank you!
Can I use std::unique_ptr the same way?

Comment: Yep, even better.